# Android game freeze for half second

Tags: java, android, libgdx, freeze

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm trying to make a game for android using LibGDX. I don't understand why it freezees for less than half second all the game (running on desktop) and if I run it on my phone or on the Emulator the freezing time is longer than half a second. This is the code:

```
    @Override
public void show() {
       stage = new Stage(physicWidth, physicHeight, true);
       gun = new ArrayList<Guns>();
       buildingAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("ui/cladiri.pack"));
   buildingSkin = new Skin(buildingAtlas);
   building1 = new ImageButton(buildingSkin.getDrawable("cladire1"));
   building2 = new ImageButton(buildingSkin.getDrawable("cladire2"));

       table = new Table();
   table.setBounds(0, tileH * 4, tileW * 6, tileH);
   table.left();
   table.add(building1).width((float) (tileW * 0.8)).height((float) (tileH * 0.7));
   table.add(building2).width((float) (tileW * 0.8)).height((float) (tileH * 0.7));
       stage.addActor(table);
       Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

       building1.addListener(new InputListener(){
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            gun.add(new Guns(selectedTile.x, selectedTile.y));
            return true;
        }
    });
    building2.addListener(new InputListener(){
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            System.out.println("Touch on Building 2");
            return true;
        }
    });

    }


    @Override
public void render(float delta) {
    batch.begin();
    for(int i = 0; i < gun.size(); i++){
      gun.get(i).render(batch, tileW, tileH);
    }
    batch.end();
    }
```

The Guns class is:

```
public Guns(float x, float y) {
    this.y = y;
    this.x = x;
    gunTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("img/gunTest1.png"));
    TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(gunTexture, gunTexture.getWidth() / 
            COLS, gunTexture.getHeight() / ROWS);
    gunFrames = new TextureRegion[COLS * ROWS];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
                    cladireFrames[index++] = tmp[i][j];
            }
    }
    gunAnimation = new Animation(0.1f, gunFrames);
    stateTime = 0f;

    bounds = new Rectangle();
}

public void update(){
    stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    curGunFrame = gunAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
}

public void render(SpriteBatch batch, float w, float h){
    batch.draw(getCurGunFrame(), x, y, w, h); 
}
```

If touched the building2 button who execute the "System.out.println" the game doesn't freeze, but on building1 who adds a new Gun then it does freeze.

The code I posted is simplified, only whats relevant to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like one of these lines will be causing your problem:

```
gunTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("img/gunTest1.png"));
TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(gunTexture, gunTexture.getWidth() / 
        COLS, gunTexture.getHeight() / ROWS);
```

Texture loading is often an expensive operation, you're then operating on it after loading it in and one, or both of these operations is almost certainly going to be causing the lag you are experiencing. I believe a standard mechanism to solve this problem is to share textures between objects and load the texture when the level starts, rather than while it's running.

Rather than having your Gun class creating a new texture on creation, your game should pass the texture in to the constructor along with the x and y variables.

The reason for the different lag times experienced between your desktop and your phone is most likely because your desktop is a lot more powerful.

Comment: Loading the texture in the level and passing to my Guns object resolved the lag/freeze problem. Many thanks sir.

Comment: Also, as a suggestion, think about using the AssetLoader class... it will perform those operations asynchronously, so you could load the assets smoothly in a load screen while showing some animation or whatever... :)